# Tracking down an elusive and slow anon_inode from lsof and Apache strace

Tags: apache-2.2, lsof, strace

Experiencing an intermittent issue with a LAMP application wherein Apache forks to its ServerLimit and grinds to a (near) halt. An `strace` on any `httpd` process shows numerous, slow `epoll_wait` calls.

```
1.254721 epoll_wait(14, {{EPOLLIN, ...
3.296430 epoll_wait(14, {{EPOLLIN, ...
1.018047 epoll_wait(14, {{EPOLLIN, ...
1.279721 epoll_wait(14, {{EPOLLIN, ...
1.145649 epoll_wait(14, {{EPOLLIN, ...
1.269836 epoll_wait(14, {{EPOLLIN, ...
1.094779 epoll_wait(14, {{EPOLLIN, ...
1.205911 epoll_wait(14, {{EPOLLIN, ...
9.052785 epoll_wait(14, {{EPOLLIN, ...
1.116279 epoll_wait(14, {{EPOLLIN, ...
1.027709 epoll_wait(14, {{EPOLLIN, ...
1.178679 epoll_wait(14, {{EPOLLIN, ...
1.336032 epoll_wait(14, {{EPOLLIN, ...
2.541861 epoll_wait(14, {{EPOLLIN, ...
1.113012 epoll_wait(14, {{EPOLLIN, ...
```

An `lsof` on the same process claims this is an `anon_inode`:

```
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE      SIZE     NODE NAME
httpd   9709 apache   14u  0000      0,7         0      373 anon_inode
```

Any insight as to what that could be, or advice to track down that information?

Answer (score 1):

This is fundamentally `lsof` not reporting as well as it should.  I can reproduce this on Ubuntu 14.04, but in a newer Ubuntu I see:

`perl    511299 frew    3u  a_inode   0,11        0    9666 [eventpoll]`

Which is pretty clear.  Basically, that epoll file descriptor will always look slow because it is literally the kernel blocking on either a timeout or events on a number of other file descriptors.  See `epoll(7)` for more details.